# Show a module on k2 category page but not in item page

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

I am trying to hide a module from k2 item page.
I have a menu which was linked to a k2 category and on k2 category page there is module assigned.
but i dont want to show the module in linked k2 category item.

please tell me if you have any idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add on top of your index.php

```
<?php $view = $_REQUEST['view']; ?>
<?php $option = $_REQUEST['option']; ?>
```

find your module and add the option and view

```
<?php if ($this->countModules( 'your_mod_position' ) && $option=='com_k2' && $view=='itemlist') : ?>
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="your_mod_position" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Login as Joomla Administrator and go to the Module Manager. Locate the module and look in the lower-left of the screen where you can assign which pages you want the module to appear.

Answer (score 0):

If Edward's solution doesn't work for your scenario, try [Advanced Module Manager](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/modules-management/10307) . It will let you assign or remove the module from specific pages and/or their children. It-s very flexible.